# Where can I find the entry mount point of Icecast2 in Linux?

Tags: linux, icecast, mount-point

I setup my [icecast2](https://icecast.org/) server reading this [tutorial](https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-install-icecast-audio-streaming-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/) in my ubuntu server.

Icecast2 service and web page only works with full url like `http://my-url:8000/sample.mp3`. I can't find where is the entry mount point even I tried to find in this [docs](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html).
(I tried almost things related with the `mount` word)

Where is the entry mount point and where do I have to list my music files?

(Or does it not exist?)

Answer (score 0):

While you could specify default mounts in your config, it's most often that the mount point is specified by your encoder/source client.

Icecast doesn't handle your music files.  You need some sort of source client to handle playout of your music, encode the continuous live stream, and send it to Icecast for streaming.